# How to use include() properly?

Tags: php, require

This is my structure directory:

```
Main directory
  all.php
  file.php
  URL1.txt
  SubDirectory1
     URL2.txt
     file.php
```

File **file.php** like this:

```
 $filename = glob("URL*");
 echo $filename[0];
```

File **all.php**

```
<?php
    include('./SubDirectory1/file.php');

?>
```

The problem is when I run file **all.php**, the browser show **URL1.txt**. Why it doesn't show URL2.txt. How to fix it ? Thank you !

Comment: Because the script `file.php` gets executed from the location of `all.php` so in this folder only `URL1.php` is found!

Comment: Try this `glob("SubDirectory1/*");`

Comment: @ Indrasinh Bihola, Hi, There is any way to add SubDirectory automatically ? Because I have a lot of subdirectory, so, it is hard to change one by one.

Comment: Check this out : http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

working directory is set to main script location. try putting full path of location you want to search in:

```
 $filename = glob(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'URL*');
```

`__DIR__` is current file directory (since PHP 5.3, for lower php version use `dirname(__FILE__)`).

http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Answer (score 0):

Just put this function into `file.php`. You will get an array back which you can `var_dump()`.

```
function glob_recursive($pattern) {
    $files = glob($pattern);

    foreach (glob(dirname($pattern).'/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR|GLOB_NOSORT) as $dir)
        $files = array_merge($files, glob_recursive($dir.'/'.basename($pattern)));

    return $files;
}
```

In your `all.php` file you can just do this:

```
print_r(glob_recursive("URL*"));
```

And you will get all file names with this pattern! So the you can use your `file()` function